# Compiler doesn't output anything although my function has been called

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to create a program to count the number of times a letter is in a string, however the following program does not output anything, although the function `count()` has definitely been called.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int count(const string &s, char c) {
    string::const_iterator i = find(s.begin(), s.end(), c);
    int n = 0;
    while (i != s.end()) {
        ++n;
        i = find(i+1, s.end(), c);
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {
    const string e = "dddddddd";
    char d = 'd';
    count(e, d);
}
```

Comment: `count` doesn't produce any output. What exactly do you expect to happen, and why?

Comment: Maybe you wanted `std::cout <<  count(e, d) <<  '\n';` instead of `count(e, d);`

Comment: Greatly simplified: `for (char ch : s) {n += (c==ch)?1:0;} return n;`

Comment: Where did you ask the computer to output anything?

Comment: Slightly on the niticky side, the compiler will never produce the expected output. The program (if correct) will generate output, when it is executed. The compiler is not involved at that point anymore.

Comment: @selbie I would not describe that as simple. Short yes. Faster maybe. Solving the lack of output problem? Never. The whole of the function you are discussing is irrelevant for at least two solutions of the problem, see the answers below. The solution can be forced into that function, but you did not.

Comment: @Yunnosch - I was not attempting to solve the OP's question, as it had already been answered before I wrote the comment. Many questions on SO are from those new to programming. As such, they have answers they seek to a specific problem, but the structure of the posted code suggests they could benefit from additional coaching. However, SO really is designed for strict questions and exact answers. There's no facility for saying, "here's something else to think about", or "here's a better way to structure your code". The best I can do is make simple suggestions in comments when possible.

Comment: But I can share a link with the OP on other approaches: https://onlinegdb.com/ryXCSj-Tr

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I completely forgot about actually doing something with the value I got from the function, a silly error on my part.

Comment: @selbie Indeed I am only just getting to grips with the standard library, and c++ in general, so any feedback to improve it is appreciated.

Comment: Since you appear OK with using `std::find`, I wonder why you wouldn't just use [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) and make your function a one-liner.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik part of the reason why I wanted to create the program so was that I got confident with using std::count() by building it from scratch, I was ok with std::find().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the standard output function cout to output your result.

```
std::cout << count(e,d);
```

Return doesn’t output anything.

Comment: This has the necessary minimum of explanation, is otherwise short and still helpful. And the best: by a new contributor. Thank you for allowing me this refreshingly nice experience today. Just for good luck, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You don't see any output because you didn't code your program to output anything. Your `count()` function has a return value that you are ignoring.

Change this line

```cpp
count(e, d);
```

To this instead

```cpp
cout << count(e, d);
```

That being said, your `count()` function is redundant as `<algorithm>` already defines a [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) function that you can use instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const std::string e = "dddddddd";
    char d = 'd';
    std::cout << std::count(e.begin(), e.end(), d);
}
```